# jList not displaying data from custom model?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist

I'm trying to populate a JList through subclassing the AbstractListModel.I have looked through numerous places to try and find what I was doing wrong, but never managed to resolve the problem.So this class handles my GUI...

```
//View
public class central extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public central() {
    initComponents();
    list.addMouseListener(new abstracts.mouseActions(list));

}

public void setListModel(ListModel l ){
    list.setModel(l);

}

// The rest are auto generated code for the interface, not relevant
```

Then is my middle class...

```
 public class MainCtrl {
//View reference
private views.central mainFrame = new views.central();
//Model reference
private abstracts.ListData model = new abstracts.ListData();
/*All this was testing purposes and it worked
  private DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
 */

private void showView(){
    mainFrame.setListModel(model);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    models.contact p2 = new models.contact("Alex", "Christopher","alex@hotmail.com","22","Def");
    models.contact p1 = new models.contact("Joes", "Smith","joey@hotmail.com","33","Def");
    model.addContact(p2);
    model.addContact(p1);
    /* def version
      model.addElement(p2);

    */


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        new MainCtrl().showView();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then I have got the AbstractListModel implementation

```
public class ListData extends AbstractListModel {    
//Store people info
private Vector<contact> people; 

public ListData() {
    people = new Vector<contact>();
}

public void addContact(contact newPerson){
   people.add(newPerson);
   int per = people.indexOf(newPerson);
   fireIntervalAdded(this,0,getSize());
}

@Override
public contact getElementAt(int index){
    return  people.get(index);
}

@Override
public int getSize(){
    return people.size();
}


@Override
protected void fireIntervalAdded(Object src, int index, int index2){
 System.out.println(index2);    
}

.....
```

I tested DefautListModel and it displayed the values, but when I incorporate  a custom model it doesn't display ? Is there a extra step I'm missing ? Also mainCtrl is the main class...

Thanks could really use some help

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `I tested DefautListModel and it displayed the values' - so why are you creating a custom model? You aren't adding any new functionality. If you want to know how the default model works then look at the source code to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: well ok but I want a custom model so that firstly I can manage my data of people array through the model. Secondly I am going to implement a Database class which will execute queries etc. So therefore a custom model would create a bridge between model -> Database...hence would not need to update model, update object array and then update database on three separate procedures. But rather onfireContentChanged would handle code for running the necessary queries.I understand what you mean though, I was just curious if I would benefit more from a custom model

Comment: I'm use a DefaultListModel<MyModel> it's work refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263649/jlist-not-displaying-data-from-custom-model)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`fireIntervalAdded(this,0,getSize());`

in your addContact() put

`fireContentsChanged(this,0,getSize());`

Answer (score -1):

```
 listModel = new DefaultListModel();
 listModel.addElement("Jane Doe");
 listModel.addElement("John Smith");
 listModel.addElement("Kathy Green");


 list = new JList(listModel);
```

please refer this link it will help you

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html